# Check the existence of the element inside the nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, lodash

I have below array of JSON. I want to set schedules for the `dayOfWeek` which are not present inside the `schedules`

```
const dummy = { home1: "09:30", away: "05:30" }
const data = {
  rooms: [
    {
      roomId: 1,
      schedules: [
        { home1: "05:05", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "20:30" },
        { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "21:30" },
        { home1: "07:05", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "22:30" }
      ]
    },
    {
      roomId: 2,
      schedules: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I am little bit confused. I need to copy the same `schedules` to the `room: 2` which are in `room: 1` and which are not present I want to set dummy with the `dayOfWeek`

expected output

```
const finalArray = [
  //room: 1
  { home1: "09:30", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "05:30", roomId: 1 },  //dummy
  { home1: "09:30", dayOfWeek: 3, away: "05:30", roomId: 1 },   //dummy
  { home1: "09:30", dayOfWeek: 4, away: "05:30", roomId: 1 },   //dummy
  { home1: "09:30", dayOfWeek: 6, away: "05:30", roomId: 1 }    //dummy

  //room: 2
  { home1: "05:05", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "20:30", roomId: 2 }, //schedules from room1
  { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "21:30", roomId: 2 }, //schedules from room1
  { home1: "07:05", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "22:30", roomId: 2 }, //schedules from room1 
  { home1: "09:30", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "05:30", roomId: 2 }, //dummy
  { home1: "09:30", dayOfWeek: 3, away: "05:30", roomId: 2 },//dummy
  { home1: "09:30", dayOfWeek: 4, away: "05:30", roomId: 2 },//dummy
  { home1: "09:30", dayOfWeek: 6, away: "05:30", roomId: 2 }//dummy
]
```

**What I have tried**

I can set the dummy data from the first element of the schedules. But don't know how to check for every element inside the `rooms.schedules` array

```
const dummy = _.first(data.rooms[0].schedules) ? _.first(rooms[0].schedules) : { 'home1': '05:30', 'home2': '09:30', 'away': '17:30', 'sleep': '20:30' }

const finalArray = []
let output = []
for (let room of data.rooms) {
  let days = []
  room.schedules.map(s => days.push(parseInt(s.dayOfWeek)))
  days = new Set(days)
  for(let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    if(!days.has(i)) finalArray.push({ ...obj, dayOfWeek: i, id: room.id })
  }
}
```

Comment: The logic for when there are 2 rooms makes sense, the `dayOfWeek`s for each room get inverted, in a sense, and room 1's objects get transferred to room 2, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the situation when there are more rooms, like 3 or 4, and what to do when their `schedules` are populated too. If there was a room 3 with empty `schedules`, would its output look similar to the 7 items in `// room: 2`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok. Let me explain. There can be more than 2 `rooms` but the `schedules` are always empty for the other `rooms` (Only one room has the `schedules` objects). So I need to copy the schedules from that room and copy them to the others room schedules. And if there is no schedules inside the room  then it should be replaced by the dummy object. Am I clear??? Please ask if you have further doubts

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dummy = { home1: "09:30", away: "05:30" };
var data = {
  rooms: [{
      roomId: 1,
      schedules: [
        { home1: "05:05", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "20:30" },
        { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "21:30" },
        { home1: "07:05", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "22:30" }
      ]
    }, {
      roomId: 2,
      schedules: []
    }, {
      roomId: 3,
      schedules: []
    }
  ]
}

var finalArray = [];
var main = data.rooms[0];
for (var day = 1; day < 8; day++) {
  var sch = main.schedules.find(x => x.dayOfWeek == day);
  for (var room of data.rooms) {
    if (room != main || !sch) {
      var temp =  {
          ...{ roomId: room.roomId},
          ...{ home1: dummy.home1, dayOfWeek: day, away: dummy.away }, 
          ...sch           
      };      
      finalArray.push(temp);
    }
  }
}

console.log(finalArray.sort((a, b) => a.roomId - b.roomId));
```